# XTick for 3D plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is than an equivalent property to `XTick` for a 3D plot?  Also, is there a way to determine the number output format for the axis tick marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XTick` is a property *of axes, not plot*. Whenever you use `plot3`, you draw on axes. Thus, it is relevant.

Instead of using `XTick`, you can use `XTickLabel`. It is a cell array of strings, so you can format them beforehand, by using `sprintf`.

```
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = x.^2;
z = sin(x);
figure;plot3(x,y,z);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1' sprintf('%2.2f',pi) '3','4','5','John Doe'});
```